# enumerable properties vs. arrays

Tags: javascript

I've been bumping into this recently and I'm wondering if there are any benefits to this approach. Let's take the `cluster.workers` object:

```
{ '1': 
   Worker {
     domain: null,
     _events: { message: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     suicide: undefined,
     state: 'none',
     id: 1,
     process: 
      ChildProcess {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _closesNeeded: 2,
        _closesGot: 0,
        connected: true,
        signalCode: null,
        exitCode: null,
        killed: false,
        spawnfile: '/home/karl/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/bin/node',
        _handle: [Object],
        spawnargs: [Object],
        pid: 7687,
        stdin: null,
        stdout: null,
        stderr: null,
        stdio: [Object],
        _channel: [Object],
        _handleQueue: null,
        send: [Function],
        _send: [Function],
        disconnect: [Function],
        _disconnect: [Function] } },
  '2': 
   Worker {
     domain: null,
     _events: { message: [Function] },
//...etc.
```

There is only one reason I can see a benefit to this; That is the amount of objects are *constant*. Since it is not an array in cannot be modified in that sense.

Any other benefits?

Comment: if you do it this way you could reach the desires things like `1.worker.process.ChildProcess.domain`

Comment: I guess you can directly reference any record this way by using cluster.workers[ recordNumber ], but in most use cases I'd prefer an array here to be able to use array methods without Object.keys() and would make a lookup map if I have to reference records directly.

Comment: @KevinKloet: Accessing the entries based on "index" is effectively identical whether it's an array object or an object like the above: `cluster.workers[1].process.domain` or `cluster.workers["1"].process.domain` (either will work in either case). *(The `Worker` and `ChildProcess` shown above aren't levels of the hierarchy, they're the type of the object it's showing, which is why I left them out there.)

Comment: @Shilly: See my comment to Kevin above: It's just as direct with an array. More so, if the JavaScript engine can keep the array optimized.

Comment: @KevinKloet, ... but you can't write `cluster.workers.1.worker`, since property names that are numerical cannot be written out in this notation. You need to use brackets then `[1]` .

Comment: \*leans back and opens a popcorn bag\*

Comment: I know. But that requires knowledge of the index of a specific record, which can be a downside. If I need to loop over all records, I prefer using an array as a container, if I need to reference records directly I'd use an object with the record ids as keys. As I wrote above, I usually settle for pulling in records as an array and then create a reference object, since I don't like using array.find() every time I need a specific record. I guess using array.find with memoisation could maybe be superior? So any more insights are welcome, since it's an often occuring situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any benefit to it at all. You can modify that just as easily as you can modify an array: `cluster.workers["3"] = new Worker(...)` is almost exactly the same thing as `cluster.workers.push(new Worker(...))` would be if it were an array.

Remember, standard arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).<sup>1</sup> They're objects that have a particular prototype and special behavior for a certain class of property names (which we call "array indexes") and a special `length` property. In fact, the "array indexes" are strings (barring runtime optimization by the JavaScript engine), just like they are in that object.

*<sup>1</sup> (That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*

Comment: So enumerable properties in this example are just arrays without the suger, huh.

Comment: @KarlMorrison: Pretty much, yup. :-) Well put.